# Did I enter the wrong year of my birthday, or did it change without me?

Tags: support

I just noticed today that my age was wrong, so I checked my profile.  The birth year was 1974, when I was in fact born in 1975.

I'm willing to believe I entered the wrong year, but it's not a mistake I make a lot, so I wanted to ask if something nefarious happened... like a software bug or something.

Comment: Might want to ask Jon Skeet as he knows everything about date! => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479

Comment: Use the "contact us" form in the footer to send Stack Exchange a copy of your birth certificate, and I'm sure this will be resolved in a couple of days.

Comment: @Yannis Why? You can change it yourself.

Comment: I'm joking @ErwaySoftware ;)

Comment: @Yannis I kind of thought you were. But I wanted to spare the SE team from receiving 3,591 birth certificates in the mail.

Comment: @Yannis Tsk. Resolved in 6 to 8 weeks, you mean.

Comment: <tongue-in-cheek>Were you born in 1974 UTC but 1975 local time?